# Looping through list of objects - Terraform

Tags: terraform

I have variable like this (input comes from Terragrunt):

```
zones:
  zone_a:
    - name: "test"
      type: "A"
      value: "127.0.7.2"
    - name: "test2"
      type: "A"
      value: "127.0.7.3"
  zone_b:
    - name: "test3"
      type: "A"
      value: "127.0.7.5"
    - name: "test4"
      type: "A"
      value: "127.0.7.6"
```

How can I loop through it in Terraform. `for_each` doesn't seem to work as it doesn't accept list.

I would like to have many records like so:

```
resource "cloudflare_record" "record" {
  zone_id = "zone_a"
  name    = "test"
  value   = "127.0.7.2"
  type    = "A"
}
```

The same would go for every record in every zone.

Comment: Can you add some more context? For example, where do you need it? What would `for_each` be used for? You can cast a list to a set with `toset` but I'm not sure if that would help.

Comment: Just added output it should be generated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could organise your records with the zone name in them then iterate over them in a foreach putting the values in

```
variable "zones" {
  type    = any
  default = {
    zone_a = [
      {
        name = "test"
        type = "A"
        value = "127.0.7.2"
      },
      {
        name = "test2"
        type = "A"
        value = "127.0.7.3"
      }
    ]
    zone_b = [
      {
        name = "test3"
        type = "A"
        value = "127.0.7.5"
      },
      {
        name = "test4"
        type = "A"
        value = "127.0.7.6"
      }
    ]
  }
}

locals {
  records = flatten([for zone, info in var.zones: [for zone_info in info: merge({zone=zone}, zone_info)]])
}

#resource "cloudflare_record" "record" {
#  for_each = local.records
#  zone_id = each.value["zone"]
#  name    = each.value["name"]
#  value   = each.value["value"]
#  type    = each.value["type"]
#}

output "records" {
  value = local.records
}
```

**OUTPUT of RECORDS**

```
Outputs:

records = [
  {
    "name" = "test"
    "type" = "A"
    "value" = "127.0.7.2"
    "zone" = "zone_a"
  },
  {
    "name" = "test2"
    "type" = "A"
    "value" = "127.0.7.3"
    "zone" = "zone_a"
  },
  {
    "name" = "test3"
    "type" = "A"
    "value" = "127.0.7.5"
    "zone" = "zone_b"
  },
  {
    "name" = "test4"
    "type" = "A"
    "value" = "127.0.7.6"
    "zone" = "zone_b"
  },
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the cleanest or the easiest solution, but I think I managed to get to where you want. In my example it requires two transformations but should be working. The first one would require to populate a local variable with values coming from Terragrunt (the name of the variable is just an example):

```
local {
  cf = yamldecode(var.terragrunt_variable)
}
```

In the second step, you would convert the list of maps to a map of maps (also a local variable):

```
  cf_zones = { for k, val in local.cf["zones"] : k =>
    {
      for i in val : i.name => {
        "name"  = i.name
        "value" = i.value
        "type"  = i.type
      }
    }
  }
```

This gives:

```
{
  "zone_a" = {
    "test" = {
      "name" = "test"
      "type" = "A"
      "value" = "127.0.7.2"
    }
    "test2" = {
      "name" = "test2"
      "type" = "A"
      "value" = "127.0.7.3"
    }
  }
  "zone_b" = {
    "test3" = {
      "name" = "test3"
      "type" = "A"
      "value" = "127.0.7.5"
    }
    "test4" = {
      "name" = "test4"
      "type" = "A"
      "value" = "127.0.7.6"
    }
  }
}
```

In the next step, create a new local variable to be used with `for_each`:

```
  fe = merge([for k, v in local.cf_zones : {
    for zn, zv in v : "${k}-${zn}" => {
      "id"    = k
      "name"  = zv.name
      "type"  = zv.type
      "value" = zv.value
    }
    }
  ]...)
```

If you print out the `local.fe` variable, the value will be:

```
{
  "zone_a-test" = {
    "id" = "zone_a"
    "name" = "test"
    "type" = "A"
    "value" = "127.0.7.2"
  }
  "zone_a-test2" = {
    "id" = "zone_a"
    "name" = "test2"
    "type" = "A"
    "value" = "127.0.7.3"
  }
  "zone_b-test3" = {
    "id" = "zone_b"
    "name" = "test3"
    "type" = "A"
    "value" = "127.0.7.5"
  }
  "zone_b-test4" = {
    "id" = "zone_b"
    "name" = "test4"
    "type" = "A"
    "value" = "127.0.7.6"
  }
}
```

Finally, for the resource, you can use `for_each` with the local `fe` variable:

```
resource "cloudflare_record" "record" {
  for_each = local.fe
  zone_id  = each.value.id
  name     = each.value.name
  value    = each.value.value
  type     = each.value.type
}
```